Why can't a factory be used instead of a Chain of responsibility when implementing a logger?
package com.company;

enum LogLevel {
    DEBUG(0),
    INFO(1),
    WARN(2),
    ERROR(3);

    private final Integer enumCode;

    private LogLevel(Integer enumCode) {
        this.enumCode = enumCode;
    }

    private Integer getEnumCode() {
        return enumCode;
    }
}

abstract class LogProcessor {

    protected LogProcessor nextLogProcessor;

    public LogProcessor(LogProcessor nextLogProcessor) {
        this.nextLogProcessor = nextLogProcessor;
    }

    public LogProcessor() {
        this.nextLogProcessor = null;
    }

    public void log(LogLevel logLevel, String message) {
        if (this.nextLogProcessor != null) {
            this.nextLogProcessor.log(logLevel, message);
        }
    }
}

class InfoLogProcessor extends LogProcessor {

    public InfoLogProcessor(LogProcessor nextLogProcessor) {
        this.nextLogProcessor = nextLogProcessor;
    }

    public InfoLogProcessor() {
        this.nextLogProcessor = null;
    }

    public void log(LogLevel logLevel, String message) {
        if (LogLevel.INFO.equals(logLevel)) {
            System.out.println("[" + LogLevel.INFO + "] " + message);
        } else {
            System.out.println("[" + LogLevel.INFO + "] This request can't be processed");
            super.log(logLevel, message);
        }
    }
}

class WarnLogProcessor extends LogProcessor {

    public WarnLogProcessor(LogProcessor nextLogProcessor) {
        this.nextLogProcessor = nextLogProcessor;
    }

    public WarnLogProcessor() {
        this.nextLogProcessor = null;
    }

    public void log(LogLevel logLevel, String message) {
        if (LogLevel.WARN.equals(logLevel)) {
            System.out.println("[" + LogLevel.WARN + "] " + message);
        } else {
            System.out.println("[" + LogLevel.WARN + "] This request can't be processed");
            super.log(logLevel, message);
        }
    }
}

class ErrorLogProcessor extends LogProcessor {

    public ErrorLogProcessor(LogProcessor nextLogProcessor) {
        this.nextLogProcessor = nextLogProcessor;
    }

    public ErrorLogProcessor() {
        this.nextLogProcessor = null;
    }

    public void log(LogLevel logLevel, String message) {
        if (LogLevel.ERROR.equals(logLevel)) {
            System.out.println("[" + LogLevel.ERROR + "] " + message);
        } else {
            System.out.println("[" + LogLevel.ERROR + "] This request can't be processed");
            super.log(logLevel, message);
        }
    }
}

public class CombinedClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LogProcessor logProcessor = new InfoLogProcessor(new WarnLogProcessor(new ErrorLogProcessor()));
        logProcessor.log(LogLevel.INFO, "This is an info message");
        System.out.println();
        logProcessor.log(LogLevel.WARN, "This is an warn message");
        System.out.println();
        logProcessor.log(LogLevel.ERROR, "This is an error message");
    }
}

Above is my code for implementing a logger using the chain of responsibility design pattern:
Classes : A runner (for main code), LogProcessor interface (and it's implementations using the chain of responsibility pattern) and log level enum.
I have gone through many resources, but still haven't found a concrete reason on why a factory method/simple factory  design pattern can't be used here. Most of the answers vaguely say that factory is a creational design pattern and hence can't be used here. My question is exactly why? Even if it is a creational pattern, it can do the same work for me in a comparatively lesser time. Chain of responsibility here has a O(n) complexity in the worst case, while factory can do it in lesser time O(1) (if maintained via a map). Can somebody please help me with a concrete answer?

You  don't need to redefine the 2 constructors in the child classes

@azro I am getting an error without those constructors. Can you help me on how to make it work without the constructors in the child class?

@jamesgem You do need them; azro doesn't know what they are talking about. You may want to implement them with, respectively, super(nextLogProcessor); and super(); (or even nothing at all, which implies super()) respectively.

you can always combine 2 patterns for better performance and design, for example, you can combine COR with Composite or Factory Pattern. In your given example (Logging) when you implement a factory pattern via Map the space complexity will be 0(N) and also COR provides below flexibility in comparison to Factory.

The Chain of Responsibility pattern is commonly used in software systems where multiple objects may handle a request, but the exact handler isn’t known at compile time.
The chain of Responsibility works on an object tree and you can change the sequence of the chain dynamically for handling.
The most important feature of COR is if no object in the chain can handle the request, it can either be handled by a default handler.


The Chain of Responsibility pattern is commonly used in software systems where multiple objects may handle a request, but the exact handler isn’t known at compile time.
In a factory as well, multiple handlers which can handle the request can be defined in an if else

The chain of Responsibility works on an object tree and you can change the sequence of the chain dynamically for handling.
Same can be done in a factory?

The most important feature of COR is if no object in the chain can handle the request, it can either be handled by a default handler.
default block in a switch case can do the same?
